# Projection of convex set onto a convex set

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, convexity

1. Can projection of convex sets onto convex sets be non-convex yet connected? If so is there any necessary and sufficient conditions?
2. Can projection of $n$ dimensional convex sets in $\mathbb R^{n'}$ onto $m$ dimensional convex sets in $\mathbb R^{m'}$ with $m<m'<n<n'$ produce non-convex connected sets of dimension smaller than $m$?

Comment: What happens if you project a line onto a ball? It's not convex right? Or a full cylinder onto a well-aligned circle for your question 2?

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by a projection?

Comment: Clarify your question and I will try to reopen it, or delete it if you don't really know what the question is about.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I do not remember what the context of the question was about. Anyway I have accepted an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this answers (1). $P$ is the pyramid illustrated.
$S$ is a square resting on the apex of $P$, at height $z_1$.
Projecting $S$ down (green lines) onto $P$ results in the nonconvex shape
outlined in red. The projection only reaches $z_2$ on the thin
side faces, but much further down to $z_3$ on the front and back faces.
The front/back faces are slanted more steeply than the left/right faces.
So, *Yes*: Projection of a convex set $S$ onto a convex set $P$ can be nonconvex
and connected.

---

[image: convexity]